# LibGDX Matrix4 3d rotation problems given direction vector3

Tags: matrix, 3d, rotation, libgdx, transform

By now I am so confused that I'm not sure of my vector math anymore.. I have a Matrix4: MatrixA  representing an objects (sensor cube) world transform. I want to place this object so that it's forward direction is pointing in the same direction as a given normalized Vector3: VecA . I also want to translate the objects (i.e. 4 units) in VecA's direction from a given point: VecB (the translation part works, using the same direction vector, VecA)

I have tried all the ways I can think of including rotate()+translate(), setToWorld(), setToLookAt(), setToRotation(), manually editing the values (column 3) of the Matrix4 (this gave the best results in terms of rotation but I get a skewed cube)

I know my direction vector (VecA) is OK. (by printing it's value and also visually confirming it by looking at the working translation using the same vector)

Can someone please tell me how I should do to achieve my desired results, thanks!

Comment: A transformation matrix doesn't have a "forward direction", but it can contain a rotation. So, you'll have to define what the unrotated forward direction is as well. Also, there are typically an infinite amount possible transformations to represent the rotation of a single vector (your forward direction). To make sure to get the result you want, you should at least define an additional (e.g. "up" or "right") direction (both rotated and unrotated) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're unrotated "forward direction" is (0,0,1), your unrotated "up direction" is (0,1,0) and you don't want to rotate the up direction (if possible), then something like this (untested code) should be what you need:

```
Vector3 vx = new Vector3(), vy = new Vector3(), vz = new Vector3();
Matrix4 m = new Matrix4();
...
vecB.set(vecA).scl(4.f); // if understand correctly, this is what you want
vz.set(vecA).nor();
vx.set(vz).crs(0, 1, 0).nor();
vy.set(vz).crs(vx).nor();
m.idt();
m.val[Matrix4.M00] = vx.x; m.val[Matrix4.M01] = vx.y; m.val[Matrix4.M02] = vx.z;
m.val[Matrix4.M10] = vy.x; m.val[Matrix4.M11] = vy.y; m.val[Matrix4.M12] = vy.z;
m.val[Matrix4.M20] = vz.x; m.val[Matrix4.M21] = vz.y; m.val[Matrix4.M22] = vz.z;
m.trn(vecB);
```

It is possible that you need to switch the `crs` arguments though (e.g. `vy.set(vx).crs(vz).nor()`, in case the rotation is upside-down). Alternatively you could use a `Quaternion` to specify the rotation and use `m.set(vecB, rotationQuaternion);`.

Comment: Thanks that worked great. There are a few things I don't get though. Shoulden't m.trn(vecB) do the same as m.translate(vecB) ? I also don't quite get why I could not use any of the Matrix4 methods to get the rotation I wanted: i.e. setToLookAt() or setToRotation(), is it because of the undefined up/right directions you talked about? I thought that was what I did in for example setToLookAt(direction, Vector3.Y)? Using 0,1,0 as up. Any clarification would be much appreciated, thanks again.

Comment: `trn` just updates the position, `translate` "post-multiplies" so it will translate after the rotation (or on the rotated "directions"). `setToLookAt` does basically the same, except that it will invert the z axis (direction). Check the source: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Matrix4.java#L789